# WCF Service TcpNetBinding StreamRequest not receiving stream

Tags: vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, stream

My first question so be gentle =)

The following is all .Net 4, VB.Net, in VS2010.  The end goal is to receive a (complete) stream from the client over Tcp binding, to an IIS Hosted WCF Service.  The problem I am facing is that the service is not able to read any bytes from the provided stream.  Now with the nitty gritty... I've removed a fair amount for brevity but, let me know if I've omitted something important.

The service contract is as follows:

```
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="ImageSystem")> _
Public Interface IUploadService
    <OperationContract()> _
    Function UploadFile(ByVal file As ImageUpload) As ImageUpload
End Interface
```

The data contract *ImageUpload* is as follows:

```
<MessageContract()> _
Public Class ImageUpload

#Region " Message Header "

    Private _ImageID As Nullable(Of Long)
    <MessageHeader()> _
    Public Property ImageID() As Nullable(Of Long)
        Get
            Return _ImageID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Nullable(Of Long))
            _ImageID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '... a few other value type properties

#End Region

#Region " Message Body"
    ' Do not add any more members to the message body or streaming support will be disabled!

    <MessageBodyMember()> _
    Public Data As System.IO.Stream

#End Region

End Class
```

The relevant server config/bindings are as follows (these are obviously dev environment settings only):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpStreamBinding" transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="20971520" maxReceivedMessageSize="20971520"/>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="UploadServiceBehaviour"
        name="ImageSystem.SVC.UploadService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpStreamBinding"
          contract="ImageSystem.SVC.IUploadService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:809/UploadService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="UploadServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The WCF Service is a service Library, which is hosted by a Web Application.  The Web Application project runs in my local IIS 7.5.  IIS has been configured to enable TCP connections, and the application pool identity is configured with relevant permissions to the contract implementation.  VS2010 is run as admin to enable debugging in IIS.

To test the contract implementation I have a Windows Console Application set up as a (test) client.  The client proxy classes were generated by adding a service reference to the service within the IIS host (http://localhost/ImageSystem/UploadService.svc).  The service reference is configured to generate async methods.

The relevant auto-generated client config is as follows (note, I've tried increasing maxBufferPoolSize, maxBufferSize, and maxReceivedMessageSize to match the servers config of "20971520", but to no avail):

*[EDIT: reliableSessions section commented out in light of Sixto Saez's suggestion but to no avail]*

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IUploadService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Streamed" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="20971520"
          maxBufferSize="20971520" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="20971520">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <!--<reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />-->
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://mycomputername.mydomain/ImageSystem/UploadService.svc"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IUploadService"
        contract="UploadService.Local.IUploadService" name="NetTcpBinding_IUploadService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

The client usage is as follows:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim serviceClient As UploadService.Local.UploadServiceClient = New UploadService.Local.UploadServiceClient
    AddHandler serviceClient.UploadFileCompleted, AddressOf LocalTestCallback
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
    My.Resources.Penguins.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    serviceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "MYDOMAIN"
    serviceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "User"
    serviceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "Password123"
    serviceClient.UploadFileAsync(Nothing, ..., ms, ms) '"..." is obviously not actually here, other values omitted. "ms" is passed as UserState object in addition to fulfilling the 'Data' parameter
End Sub
```

In case you wonder (or it matters), the penguins image is the one provided with Windows 7 in the sample pictures directory. The image is 777,835 bytes (should be within the relevant request/buffer max sizes).

I have tried two approaches to read the image on the server side.

Approach 1:

```
Public Function UploadFile(ByVal file As ImageUpload) As ImageUpload Implements IUploadService.UploadFile

    Dim uploadBuffer(Helper.Settings.AppSettings(Of Integer)("UploadBufferSize", True) - 1) As Byte
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim bytesRead As Integer
    Do
        bytesRead = file.Data.Read(uploadBuffer, 0, uploadBuffer.Length)
        ms.Write(uploadBuffer, 0, bytesRead)
    Loop Until bytesRead = 0

End Function
```

Approach 2:

```
Public Function UploadFile(ByVal file As ImageUpload) As ImageUpload Implements IUploadService.UploadFile

    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(file.Data)
    Dim imageB64 As String = reader.ReadToEnd
    ms = New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(imageB64))

End Function
```

In both cases, ms.Length = 0.  More clearly, in the second approach, imageB64 = "" (empty string).

Why aren't I receiving anything from the stream?  Also, as a sneaky *sub-question*, why does the generated proxy class not provide an overload that accepts an object of type *ImageUpload*?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Is there any way of bumping this?  Only 26 views and no answer yet. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seemed strange to me that you would have the problems you mentioned, so I was curious and put together an implementation using your service contract. That one actually worked straight away. I don't actually know what went wrong in your case (it's not obvious), but let me just post a working solution here hoping that this will help you to solve your problem.

Unfortunately, as I abandoned VB many years ago, I can only provide C# code. Hope that's alright.

**Server Web.config (tested in IIS, with net.tcp binding):**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="ImageSystem.SVC.UploadService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ImageSystem.SVC.IUploadService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" kind="mexEndpoint" binding="mexTcpBinding"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Client app.config (console test app):**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000">
                <security mode="None"/>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint 
            address="net.tcp://localhost/WcfService1/UploadService.svc" 
            binding="netTcpBinding" 
            contract="ImageServices.IUploadService" 
            name="NetTcpBinding_IUploadService">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Service contract & implementation:**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="urn:ImageSystem")]
public interface IUploadService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ImageUpload UploadFile(ImageUpload file);
}

[MessageContract]
public class ImageUpload
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public long? ImageID { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream Data;
}

public class UploadService : IUploadService
{

    public ImageUpload UploadFile(ImageUpload file)
    {
        long length;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.Data.CopyTo(ms);
            length = ms.Length;
        }

        return new ImageUpload { ImageID = length, Data = new MemoryStream() };
    }
}
```

Test app:

```
private static readonly string imgPath = @"C:\Pictures\somepicture.jpg";
private static readonly EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

static void Main()
{
    long? result;

    using (var service = new ImageServices.UploadServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IUploadService"))
    {
        var image = new ImageServices.ImageUpload();
        using (var imgStream = File.OpenRead(imgPath))
        {
            image.Data = imgStream;
            service.UploadFileCompleted += (sender, e) => 
            { 
                result = e.Result;
                if (e.Data != null) image.Data.Dispose();
                waitHandle.Set();
            };

            service.UploadFileAsync(null, imgStream);

            waitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

First of all, as you can see, the config files can be a lot simpler. Especially the large `BufferSize` value is not necessary. Then, with regard to the service contract, it's not clear to me why the `Upload` operation would receive AND return an `ImageUpload` message. In my implementation, I'm returning the uploaded file size in the `ImageID` parameter just for demo purposes, of course. I don't know what your reasoning behind that contract was, and what you actually would want to return.

---

Actually, was just about to click "Send" when I had an idea why your code could have failed. In your test client, before you call `serviceClient.UploadFileAsync()`, add this line to your code: `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`.

This resets the position of the MemoryStream back to its beginning. If you don't do that, the MemoryStream will be consumed only from its current position, which is its end - and which explains the Length = 0 of the stream received on the service side!

Comment: you are my hero.  I haven't read through all the config changes completely yet, the answer was obvious as soon as I read it... "ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)".  Can't believe I missed that.  Thank you for your time on this.  The reason the server had transferMode set to Streamed is because there are several other operations on the contract, some of which return streams, so although no single operation both receives and responds with streams, the contract as a whole does.  The config I'm using is probably so verbose because most was done in the WCF Config Wizard. C# was fine

Comment: I'm not allowed to award you a bounty until a 24 hour period is up.  I'll check back in 4 hours to award it.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may have already [seen the information in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) but you should review the section called Streaming Data and the restrictions it lists. Your client config shows the reliableSession element having the ordered attribute set to "true" which is not supported for streaming.

I don't know if that is specifically the cause of your issue but it is a start. That article also layouts pretty well the basic config required for streaming so you should ensure your config complies with its recommendations.

Comment: I have seen that article, but hadn't noticed the reliable session on the client auto-gen config.  Will try that now and let you know!  EDIT: I deleted the reliableSession section but no such luck.  If I remove that section will it default to reliableSession being enabled?

Comment: I'll answer for you (though correct me if I'm wrong)... [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733136.aspx) says netTcpBindings "support a reliable session as an option but do not enable one by default".  Thanks for your time in spotting that though.

Comment: No problem but just to be clear, streaming over netTcpBinding does not support the use of reliable sessions.  The quote from the article I referenced is "Because of these functional constraints, you can use only transport-level security options for streaming and you **cannot** turn on reliable sessions" (emphasis added).

Comment: Yup, I remember reading the same thing.  In my comment I was trying to double check that removing the reliableSession section from the config would disable reliableSessions as opposed to remove any mention of them, but actually leave them on due to some underlying default value.  Thanks again